# Must implement the interface while implemented this interface in a activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a Main activity. at Main Activity, in Oncreat{}, i creat a fragment with name "ChannelList"
Code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //initVtcId();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.tabcontent) == null) { 

          FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
          ChannelList list = new ChannelList();
          //fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, list);

          fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.tabcontent, list);
          fragmentTransaction.commit();
      }
```

To oder to ChannelList to communicate up to a Activity with name "ChannelActivity". I use a Interface with name "OnListItemSelectedListener " and its method "onListItemSelected" in ChannelList

```
public class ChannelList extends ListFragment {
private OnListItemSelectedListener mCallback;
public interface OnListItemSelectedListener {
    public void onListItemSelected(ListView l, int position);
}
```

The Fragment ChannelList captures the interface implementation during its onAttach() lifecycle method

```
     @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
        try {
            mCallback = (OnListItemSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnListItemSelectedListener");
        }
    }
```

the following method in the fragment is called when the user clicks on a list item. The fragment uses the callback interface to deliver the event to the parent activity.

```
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    mCallback.onListItemSelected(l, mChannelAdapter.getItem(position)
            .getID());
}
```

On ChannelActivity, I implement this interface and its method to call a Fragment with name "ChannelDetailFragment"

```
public class ChannelActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ChannelList.OnListItemSelectedListener {

private FragmentManager fm;
private Fragment mChannelDetailFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.channel_activity);
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    Fragment mChannelListFragment = fm
            .findFragmentByTag(ChannelList.TAG);
    if (mChannelListFragment == null) {
        addFragment(new ChannelList(), false,
                ChannelList.TAG);
    }

}

@Override
public void onListItemSelected(ListView l, int position) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ChannelDetailFragment.CHANNEL_ID, position);

    mChannelDetailFragment = fm
            .findFragmentByTag(ChannelDetailFragment.TAG);
    if (mChannelDetailFragment == null) {
        mChannelDetailFragment = new ChannelDetailFragment();
    }
    mChannelDetailFragment.setArguments(args);
    addFragment(mChannelDetailFragment, true, ChannelDetailFragment.TAG);
}
```

I follow this tut at:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver
Unfortunately, I have an error throw from OnAttach{}. I checked my code manytimes but not detect where is incorrect. Sb help me!

```
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.channellistfragment/com.example.channellistfragment.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.channellistfragment.MainActivity@a68d01b8 must implement OnListItemSelectedListener
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.channellistfragment.MainActivity@a68d01b8 must implement OnListItemSelectedListener
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at com.example.channellistfragment.ChannelList.onAttach(ChannelList.java:79)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:867)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5018)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
10-02 14:07:40.156: E/AndroidRuntime(980):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: thanks! i understand reason why it don't work

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 activities and add ChannelList fragment to both of them. First one (Main Activity) doesnt implements your callback interface and you get ClassCast exeption.

Comment: Thanks! i deleted channelactivity and implement interface on mainactivity. So it work fine! My purpose still uses channelactivity implement interface but don't implement interface on mainactivity

Comment: There is no sense. You add fragments to mainactivity, so it should have OnListItemSelectedListener implemented in some way. Why do you need second activity?